# How to fetch elements between x and y from tf.data.TFRecordDataset in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

The `test_dataset` is defined as:

```
test_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([test_tfrecords])
test_dataset = test_dataset.map(map_f)
test_dataset = test_dataset.repeat(1)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(1)
```

For fetching the first 100 elements:

```
for test in test_dataset.take(100):
    pass
```

But how to fetch elements in `index range` between 50 and 150?

```
for test in test_dataset.take([50-150]):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `tf.data.Dataset.skip`:

```
for test in test_dataset.skip(50).take(100):
    pass
```